# Prove that a function is decreasing

Tags: real-analysis, probability, functional-analysis, probability-distributions

Let $\left(\,c_m\,\right)_{m \in \mathbb{N}}$ be some coefficients which are all positive natural, $c_0=1$, and they are increasing in $m$. Define $$
f(y) = \frac{\sum\limits_{m=0} c_m \, \, ( y  \cdot  g)^m}{\sum\limits_{n=0} 
c_n\, \, y^n},
$$
where $y \in [0,1]$ and $g$ is some constant $0<g<1$. Is it true that $f(y)$ is decreasing with $y$ (at least in a positive neighbourhood of y)?

Comment: the derivative of the function is:
$$
\frac{\sum\limits_{m,n =0}^\infty ( m \cdot g^m - n \cdot  g^m) \cdot (\, c_{k+2m} \,c_{k+2n} \, y^{m+n-1}\,)}{{(\sum\limits_{n=0} 
c_n\, \, y^n)}^2}
$$
How to prove that it is negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write out the summation terms, then perform the division. With the quotient, differentiate term wise and conclude that f'(y) is negative on the given interval and variable bounds.

Comment: I can't conclude that it is negative.

Comment: p.s. see the edit

Comment: ok it is obvious!